# SQL Server 2016: Invisible Alias

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016: Alias doesn't show up but when I add it, it tells me it's a duplicate

I've got an alias that I'm sure I created under SQL Server Configuration Manager>>SQL Native 11 (32bit)>>Aliases.  However, the alias disappeared.  So I tried to recreate it, but when I try to add it, it gives me a WMI Provider Error claiming the alias already exists.  Hmm, I knew that I had created it.  How do I delete or edit an alias that is invisible?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I simple edited the registry to fix this:
Run Regedt32
Go to:
local machines\software\Wow6432Node\Microsft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

Somehow it changed the alias from the normal Reg value:
DBMSSOCN,servername\SQLExpress,518

to:
DBNMPNTW,servername\SQLExpress,518

As soon as I put DBMSSOCN back, the alias showed back up.